# How to package jar from one project to another in maven multimodule project

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-plugin, packaging, multi-module

I need a best-practice solution for the following problem. I have a maven multi-module project with 3 subprojects:

- client-module (simple java app which packaged as .jar)
- module-1-that-uses-client
- module-2-that-uses-client

module-*-that-uses-client is a bunch of static xml config files with a client-module.jar which is packaged as a .zip file. So, the packaged structure of a module-*-that-uses-client would look like:

- client-module.jar
- config1.xml
- config2.xml
- config3.xml

I wonder how I can implement following build strategies.
If I build client-module, then:

1. build client-module
2. copy client-module.jar to all module-*-that-uses-client
3. build all module-*-that-uses-client modules.

If I build any of module-*-that-uses-client, then:

1. build client-module
2. copy client-module.jar to exact module-*-that-uses-client
3. build exact module-*-that-uses-client modules.

Appreciate any help on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be the usage of `--also-make` and `--also-make-dependents`.

`--also-make` builds all dependencies of the specified module. Example: `mvn --projects module-1-that-uses-client --also-make clean install` builds client-module and module-1-that-uses-client in this order.

`--also-make-dependents` builds the specified module and all other modules with a dependency to the specified module. Example: `mvn --projects client-module --also-make-dependents clean install` builds first client-module and then both module-*-that-uses-client.

See also the [Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

Comment: Roland, thanks for your answer. Can use maven-assembly to put dependencies from the maven repository?